# How do I paste a image on a email message

Tags: php, html, forms, email, message

Oke, this is a tricky one. (I think).
Do you know when you receive a message and the email has a image on top or on the bottom of the page.
I have been trying to make it but can't figure it out.
I hope you guy's can help me with this problem.

This is what I got so far;

```
    <?php 
    $to = 'info@gmail.com';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $gast = $_POST['email'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
    $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
    $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 



    if(empty($errors))
    {

    $to = $to;
    $from = $gast;
    $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
    $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
    fclose($file);

    $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

    $body = "E-mail".
    "Name: $name\n".
    "Email: $gast \n".
    "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n". 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n". 
    $data;  

    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Email: $gast \r\n";
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n";
    $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 
    $headers .= "img src='http://cache.estivant.nl/image/1399025430_12_banners-bestemmingen-single-1680x460-extra2-06-kos_1399025430.jpg' alt='image'";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    mail($to, $body, $headers);

    }
    }

    ?>


    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="">

    <label for="name">name</label>
    <input type="name" name="name" value="" />

    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" />

    <button id="submit" name="submit">send</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write a html page with css styles and format your email accordingly and use the html as your email body. This will create an image in the mail

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image"></img>
```

Please be aware that most (if not all) email clients will block your image from being showed to your receiver as long as you are not in their trusted sender list or contact list.

Of course, your email has to be sent as html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a nicely formatted email with images.

Note image syntax: `<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />'`

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Request';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['req-name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Type of Change:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['typeOfChange']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Urgency:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['urgency']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (main):</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['URL-main'] . "</td></tr>";
$addURLS = $_POST['addURLS'];
if (($addURLS) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (additional):</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($addURLS) . "</td></tr>";
}
$curText = htmlentities($_POST['curText']);           
if (($curText) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>CURRENT Content:</strong> </td><td>" . $curText . "</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>NEW Content:</strong> </td><td>" . htmlentities($_POST['newText']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Code source and full explanation: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/